# Changing XML source on click using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I have a simple newsfeed which is pulling from an xml file which works great.  The news feed is broken down into separate XML files for each year. I want the page to show only one year at a time with links to other years above.  Ideally when a new year is clicked I would like the content below to update without going to a new page.

I am trying to avoid repeating the PHP code which is parsing the XML for each year and instead would like to simply update the $dom_object->load source when the user clicks a different year.

I am a PHP newbie so some help would be appreciated!

```
    <?php
     $dom_object = new DOMDocument();
     $dom_object->load("http://EXAMPLE.com/XML-Feed-10100524539?year=2013");
     $item = $dom_object->getElementsByTagName("item");

     foreach( $item as $value )
     {
     $titles = $value->getElementsByTagName("title");
     $title  = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

     $pubDates = $value->getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
     $pubDate  = $pubDates->item(0)->nodeValue;

     $pdf_urls = $value->getElementsByTagName("pdf_url");
     $pdf_url  = $pdf_urls->item(0)->nodeValue;
     //Trims after last space - REMOVES EST
     $pubDate=substr($pubDate, 0, strrpos($pubDate, ' '));
     //Trims after remaining space - REMOVES TIME
     $pubDate=substr($pubDate, 0, strrpos($pubDate, ' '));
     $pubDater = str_replace('/', '-', $pubDate);
     $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $pubDate);
    $newDate = $newDate->format('F d, Y'); 



     echo "<div style=\"width:33%; float:left; display:inline-block; height:150px;\"><div style=\"padding:10px;\"><a href=\"$pdf_url\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"pdf news\"><h4>$newDate</h4><p>$title</p></a></div></div>";
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: I imagine the solution would be to replace the hardcoded source to a variable and then have this variable update onClick...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use ajax by using `$.get` or [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) so you could do something like:

```
$('#yourElement').click(function(){
    var path = $('#path'); // for example
    $.post("your/path/getXML.php", { path: path },
        function (dat) {
            console.log(dat);
        }
    );
});
```

Where `getXML` would be a file similar to this one:

```
$dom_object = new DOMDocument();
     $dom_object->load($_POST["path"]);
     $item = $dom_object->getElementsByTagName("item");

     foreach( $item as $value )
     {
     $titles = $value->getElementsByTagName("title");
     $title  = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

     $pubDates = $value->getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
     $pubDate  = $pubDates->item(0)->nodeValue;

     $pdf_urls = $value->getElementsByTagName("pdf_url");
     $pdf_url  = $pdf_urls->item(0)->nodeValue;
     //Trims after last space - REMOVES EST
     $pubDate=substr($pubDate, 0, strrpos($pubDate, ' '));
     //Trims after remaining space - REMOVES TIME
     $pubDate=substr($pubDate, 0, strrpos($pubDate, ' '));
     $pubDater = str_replace('/', '-', $pubDate);
     $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $pubDate);
    $newDate = $newDate->format('F d, Y'); 

    echo "<div style=\"width:33%; float:left; display:inline-block; height:150px;\"><div style=\"padding:10px;\"><a href=\"$pdf_url\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"pdf news\"><h4>$newDate</h4><p>$title</p></a></div></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I tried the above but it doesn't seem to work.  I replaced the path for getXML and referenced #yourElement as the id of an a tag.  Any other ideas of why this wouldn't work?  I am using Wordpress.